# Problema sobre conversión de monedas en un vector unidimensional en C

Tags: c

Intento hacer un programa en C sobre una conversión de monedas en un vector unidimensional, pero los resultados aparecen en `int` y los quiero en `float`:

```
//CONVERSIONES_VECTOR.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
void Calcular (float PESOS[], int tam);
void Presenta (float a[], float b[], float c[], float t);
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{ HANDLE hCon;
hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD dwPos;
dwPos.X=x;
dwPos.Y=y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon,dwPos);
}

int main( )
{ const int TAM=5;
float PESOS[5];
int I;
system("cls");
gotoxy(20,3);printf("CONVERSION DE PESOS A DOLARES Y LIBRAS");
gotoxy(20,5);printf("Nombre: Santiago Arias Paul  Grupo: 2APRM  Fecha: 13/03/2023");
gotoxy(20,7);printf("Llena el Arreglo[] con 5 numero");
for (I=1;I<=TAM;I++)
{ gotoxy(20,10+I);printf("Arreglo[%f]=",I);
scanf("%f",&PESOS[I]);
}
Calcular(PESOS,TAM);
return 0;
}
void Calcular (float PESOS[], int tam)
{ float DOLARES[5], LIBRAS[5];
int I;
for(I=1;I<=tam;I++)
{
DOLARES[I]=PESOS[I]*.054;
LIBRAS[I]=PESOS[I]*.045;
}
Presenta(PESOS,DOLARES,LIBRAS,tam);
}

void Presenta (float a[], float b[],float c[],float t)
{ int I;
system("cls");
gotoxy(20,5);printf( "PESOS[] DOLARES[] LIBRAS[]");
for(I=1;I<=t;I++)
{ gotoxy(24,6+I);printf("%f",a[I]);
gotoxy(37,6+I);printf("%f",b[I]);
gotoxy(49,6+I);printf("%f",c[I]);
}
gotoxy(20,20);printf("PULSA UNA TECLA PARA SALIR");
getche();
system("cls");
}
```

Los resultados me los da en entero y los quiero en decimal.

Ya intente cambiarle todas las variables a `float`, sin embargo sigue sin darme los resultados de los dos vectores en decimal, sino que me los da en entero, no se porque y tampoco se como arreglar este problema.

Comment: el ultimo texto solo copie lo mismo y pegue por el hecho de que no me dejaba enviar la pregunta, espero la puedan resolver

Comment: Tuve que adaptar el código para poder probarlo, pero [funciona](https://bit.ly/3YBluV7). Aunque no obtengas ningún error, la numeración debería comenzar por 0. Parece que el problema no se puede reproducir.